# Multiple fallback URLs with identification of successful URL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I would like to be able to define more than one fallback URL, while also being able to identify which URL eventually succeeded. As I understand, without the added requirement of identifying the successful URL, this is simple enough to achieve with multiple calls to [`error()`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/430/com/bumptech/glide/RequestBuilder.html#error-com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder-).

By adapting the example shown [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html#you-cant-start-or-clear-loads-in-requestlistener-or-target-callbacks), I assume something like this could be done:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .error(Glide.with(fragment)
     .load(fallbackUrl1))
  .error(Glide.with(fragment)
     .load(fallbackUrl2))
  .error(Glide.with(fragment)
     .load(fallbackUrl3))
  .into(imageView);
```

But, as I mentioned, what if I need to perform subsequent operations in my program in accordance with which URL succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the desired effect by adding a [`RequestListener`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestListener.html). A general usage example can be found [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html#requestlistener-and-custom-logs).

But first, I'd like to clarify that declaring multiple fallbacks is not achieved through chaining calls to `error()`, but rather by nesting them. So instead of what I showed in my question it would be:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .error(Glide.with(fragment)
     .load(fallbackUrl1)
     .error(Glide.with(fragment)
        .load(fallbackUrl2)
        .error(Glide.with(fragment)
           .load(fallbackUrl3)
        )
     )
  )
  .into(imageView);
```

Not my favorite paradigm, but there you have it. As mentioned, in addition to that, `RequestListener`s were used, which set a variable indicating the request they represent (and by relation, the fallback URL) if said request was successful.

Using an example with just one fallback URL for clarity, it looks something like this:

```
var successfulURLIndex = 0

Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(url)
    .error(
        Glide.with(fragment)
            .load(fallbackURL1)
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    Log.i("MainActivity", "fallback 1 fail")
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Drawable?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    dataSource: DataSource?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    successfulURLIndex = 1
                    Log.i("MainActivity", "fallback 1 success")
                    return false
                }
            })
    .into(imageView)
```

`onResourceReady` and `onLoadFailed` are called when the request in question succeeds or fails, respectively. As such, `successfulURLIndex` is set to one if the fallback request succeeds and remains at 0 otherwise. This variable is then used to identify which URL was successful.

Since this can obviously get bulky quickly as more fallback listeners are nested, the anonymous class object (i.e. `object : RequestListener<Drawable> { ...`) can be extracted to its own class making the code more concise, even as more `error()` calls are nested as shown here:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(url)
    .error(
        Glide.with(fragment)
            .load(fallbackURL1)
            .listener(ImageLoadListener(1))
            .error(
                Glide.with(fragment)
                    .load(fallbackURL2)
                    .listener(ImageLoadListener(2))
            )
    )
    .into(imageView)
```

The value passed when instantiating `ImageLoadListener` is the fallback URL's index. This index is assigned to a singleton variable in `onResourceReady` and, similar to before, used to identify the successful URL.